# How can I get the WSDL file generated by .NET from inside the assembly?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, unit-testing, wsdl

I have an ASP.NET web service that I am trying to write unit tests for. One of the things I need to test is that the WSDL file generated from the web service matches certain criteria. However, I can't figure out how to get the WSDL file without actually doing an HTTP request to the web service.

What I would **like** to do is something like this (pseudo-code):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService]    
class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    string PopNextItem()
    {
        // Retrieve a string from the database and then delete that record.
    }
}
```

(snip)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
class WebServiceTest
{
    bool CheckWSDLMeetsCriteria(string WSDL)
    {
        bool success = true;
        // Check file here
        return success;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    void WSDL_Should_Match_Criteria()
    {
        string generatedWSDL = getWSDL(MyWebService.PopNextItem);
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckWSDLMeetsCriteria(generatedWSDL));
    }
}
```

Of course, there is no `getWSDL` method, and I'm not sure how to write one. I guess I could call wsdl.exe from the test and then get the output file, but I'm hoping there's a better way. Does .NET provide any way to generate the WSDL file programmatically?

Failing that, I suppose I could try to retrieve the WSDL file using an HTTP request to IIS. The problem is that when the unit tests are run on a local machine the local instance of IIS will probably not be running. Attempting to get the WSDL file from the staging server or something like that would result in possibly testing against an older version of the service (the web service code on my local machine might have changed since the staging server was updated), or worse I might not have internet access and would be unable to test.

I'm curious what solution others would recommend. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two possible options that you could implement so far.

**A.** Use ServiceDescriptionReflector to generate the WSDL file. [[Source](http://craigandera.blogspot.se/2004/10/generating-wsdl-without-aspnet_18.html)]

```
ServiceDescriptionReflector reflector = new ServiceDescriptionReflector(); 
reflector.Reflect(typeof(MyService), "http://localhost/vdir/Foo.asmx");

if (reflector.ServiceDescriptions.Count > 1){
  throw new Exception("Deal with multiple service descriptions later");
}

XmlTextWriter wtr = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out); 
wtr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
reflector.ServiceDescriptions[0].Write(wtr); 
wtr.Close();
```

**B.** [Use Svcutil.exe to Export Metadata from Compiled Service Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581.aspx) [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827223/how-to-generate-a-wsdl-in-c-sharp-without-making-a-http-request)]